# How do I invoke methods on a Java object created by a different method?

Tags: java

I have a method which creates an object called "OtherItem1". The "getItemName" method is from the class, and returns a String called "itemName". This works fine when I call the "getItemName" method on the "OtherItem1" object within this method. However when I am not able to call this method on the object within my main method. Is there any way to make this object accessible for other methods?

```
public static void createOtherItem() {
        System.out.print("Item Name : ");
        itemName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Price : ");
        price = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Id : ");
        id = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Stock: ");
        stock = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Department : ");
        department = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Details : ");
        details = input.next();

        OtherItem OtherItem1 = new OtherItem(itemName, price, id, stock, department, details);

        OtherItem1.getItemName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createOtherItem();
        OtherItem1.getItemName();
    }
```

Comment: OtherItem1 is not in scope in your `main()` method. It was defined inside of `createOtherItem()` and is only visible there. Try defining your method as follows: `public static OtherItem createOtherItem()` and then return OtherItem1 at the end of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could declare it as a static variable outside the method.

```
private static OtherItem OtherItem1;

public static void createOtherItem() {
    // existing code here, down to the object creation...

    // it's already declared, so you don't need to specify the type again
    OtherItem1 = new OtherItem(itemName, price, id, stock, department, details);
    OtherItem1.getItemName();
}
```

But as Carcigenicate suggested, I think it would be better to just return it to the calling method and use it as a local variable there too.

```
public static OtherItem createOtherItem() {
    // Existing code
    return OtherItem1;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OtherItem otherItem1 = createOtherItem();
    otherItem1.getItemName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also like this approach to solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`OtherItem1` exists only in the scope of method `createOtherItem` and not outside of it.

You can for example return OtherItem1 from the method and use this object:

```
public static OtherItem createOtherItem() {
    ...
    return OtherItem1;
}
```

And then in method `main`:

```
OtherItem item = createOtherItem();
```

And please do not use names beginning with uppercase letters for variable names. This is against generally accepted naming conventions.

Comment: I like this answer. Note that there are technically other ways (e.g. using a *global variable*), but this is probably the best. Using a global variable, for example, would not go well with having your methods be `static`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! You are totally right about the naming conventions, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` the object from the method.

Change the signature of the method to:

```
//            No longer void
public static OtherItem createOtherItem() {
    System.out.print("Item Name : ");
    itemName = input.next();
    System.out.print("Price : ");
    price = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Id : ");
    id = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Stock: ");
    stock = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Department : ");
    department = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Details : ");
    details = input.next();

    OtherItem OtherItem1 = new OtherItem(itemName, price, id, stock, department, details);

    OtherItem1.getItemName();

    // Return it here
    return OtherItem1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Then receive the returned item here
    OtherItem returnedItem = createOtherItem();

    // And use it here
    returnedItem.getItemName();
}
```

A couple side notes:

- Your indentation is very weird. 4 spaces of indentation is standard. You seem to be mixing tabs and spaces, and use 6 spaces, or something. It's hard to tell what's going on in the mobile editor, but it was difficult to align properly.
- Do not use capital names for plain variables. Capital names (like `OtherItem1`) are reserved for class/interface names. Improper naming conventions makes your code more difficult to read.

Comment: Thank You, that was very helpful! The indentation is done automatically by Eclipse, so not sure how I would go about changing that. You are completely correct about object names, that was my bad.